# SQLCMD version output is different for different RHEL versions for Informix

Tags: informix

We are using "sqlcmd" for working with Informix DB. Our scripts were using "info columns for " command to extract the columns and prepare/run queries.

However, moving to RHEL7, the latest version of SQLCMD is coming with different output pattern.

```
Eg: RHEL6
$ echo "info columns for <table>" | dbaccess 2>&1 | head
1|<column 1>|258|4|0
2|<column 2>|7|4|0
3|<column 3>|0|2|0
... etc

RHEL7
$ echo "info columns for <table>" | dbaccess 2>&1 | head
colno              1
colname            <column 1>
coltype            258
collength          4
extended_id        0

colno              2
colname            <column 2>
coltype            7
collength          4
```

The versions are as follows:

```
RHEL 6
$ dbaccess -V
dbaccess: SQLCMD Version 87.00 (2010-10-21)
IBM Informix CSDK Version 3.50, IBM Informix-ESQL Version 3.50.FC7
GNU Readline 6.0
(C) Copyright Jonathan Leffler 1987-2010
Licenced under GNU General Public Licence Version 2

RHEL 7
$ dbaccess -V
dbaccess: SQLCMD Version 90.02 (2016-07-28)
IBM Informix CSDK Version 4.10, IBM Informix-ESQL Version 4.10.FC2DE
GNU Readline 6.2
(C) Copyright Jonathan Leffler 1987-2016
Licenced under GNU General Public Licence Version 2
```

Do we have a solution for making the sqlcmd backward compatible? Is it some flag driven? We have to support RHEL6 and RHEL7.

Comment: I removed the [tag:sqlcmd] tag because this SQLCMD is not the one referenced by the tag (the tag says "MS SQL Server" explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only mildly biassed — I wrote [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)<sup>(1)</sup>.

The output you show from version 90.02 reflects the addition of the 'block' mode output format to emulate DB-Access better, and that format is now enabled by default when you use `sqlcmd` via the name `dbaccess`.

So, yes, there's a change of behaviour.  SQLCMD 90.02 now emulates DB-Access more closely than 87.00 did.

The problem is also not directly related to RHEL 6 vs RHEL 7; it is related to the version of SQLCMD instead.

I'm not sure there's an easy way to revert to the old behaviour.  Using `dbaccess -F select stores -` doesn't override the default in the modern version; running `format select;` as a command does.  That's a mild nuisance, but not totally surprising.  I'd be willing to set the format mode implied by the name `dbaccess` before the rest of the command line argument processing so that the command line option overrides the implied format.  Running SQLCMD via `dbaccess -C` puts it back into `sqlcmd` mode, but that means it doesn't interpret the database name and file name arguments like DB-Access does. (For example, in `dbaccess` mode, it adds a `.sql` extension to the file name if you don't add it in the first place, like DB-Access does; `sqlcmd` does not do that.)

The 'best' solution would be to modify the scripts to use SQLCMD directly.  However, that implies changing more than just the command name; you'd have to add `-d` before the database name and add `.sql` suffixes to file names.

It would be possible to change SQLCMD to add an environment variable such as `SQLCMD_FORMAT` which takes effect if not overridden explicitly on the command line.  Setting that to `select` would restore the old output format.  Another possibility might be to add support for a `.sqlcmdrc` file containing commands to be executed on start up.  I'm not convinced I want to add that, though.

I suggest contacting me via email (see the SQLCMD documentation or my SO profile) to discuss what happens from here — please include SQLCMD in the subject line.

Incidentally, as a short-term workaround, there's nothing to stop you using SQLCMD 87.00 on RHEL 7.  Or, rather, you'll probably find you need to edit `jlss.h` to either remove or update the declaration of `memmem()` — it was in the 87.00 code because I wasn't aware at the time that the function was available on some platforms — it is a part of neither C11 nor POSIX 2017.
Remove the `const` from the return type.  I get some other compilation warnings when I compile 87.00 on macOS 10.13.4 (High Sierra) with GCC 7.3.0, but they're not harmful (however undesirable they are).  But code from 2010 doesn't necessarily compile as cleanly on more modern systems.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The link may require registration with the IIUG.  That is free and does not entail a large amount of email — normally less than one per week, I'd estimate — unless you choose to subscribe to some of the discussion channels.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan. I have IIUG user account and will contact you there. As you suggested, we have downgraded the version to 87.00 as a temp solution and it is working.